# How many types of varna are there in Hinduism?

Tags: varna

I'm not asking about the types: brahmin, kshatriya, vaisya, and sudra.

I'm asking about the types of varnas itself such as astrological varna, birth-based varna, etc.,

How many such types of varnas are there in Hinduism?

Comment: Just wondering why you think those classifications are also termed varnas

Comment: There is no astrological varna but ganas that is Deva(Satva), Manushya(Rajas) and Rakshasa(Tamas) associated with the constellation of birth's rashi. But its not right to declare one divine or demonic based on gana alone as all 9 planets themselves have gunas/attributes like Jupiter is wisdom, Sun is kingship, Mars is strength etc., and effects of planets and constellations overlap based on exaltation or debilitation leading to extreme diversity within characteristics of common people.

Comment: @Carmensandiego I dont know whether they are same or different. I came across many types of varnas.